# Estoy tratando de resolverlo y me tira error, me puede ayudar. gracias

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

La función llamada 'menorMayor' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números llamado 'numeros' y debe devolver un

// arreglo que contenga el menor número del arreglo 'numeros' en la posición cero y el mayor número del arreglo
// 'numeros' en la posición 1. Esto es lo que logre hacer, puedo utilizar metodos del array.

```
var menor = numeros[0];
var mayor = numeros[1]; 
var array= [mayor, menor]
for (var i = 1; i< numeros.length; i++){ 
 if (numeros[i] >mayor){
 mayor =numeros[i]; 
} else if (numeros[i] < menor){
      menor = numeros[i]; 
  }
return array;
}
```

}

Tiene que pasar un test y este es el error que me tira

```
  menorMayor
  × should return [1, 10] for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] (19ms)
  × should return [-10, 10] for [-10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] (2ms)
  √ should return [1, 10] for [10, 1]
```

retorna correctamente el valor del array creado con mayor y menor

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Como comenta @BetaM, debes colocar el código como texto y no como imagen. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: tiene que pasar un test que ejecuto por consola.                                                 
      × should return [1, 10] for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] (18ms)
      × should return [-10, 10] for [-10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] (1ms)

Comment: sigue dando el mismo erro

 menorMayor
      × should return [1, 10] for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] (17ms)
      × should return [-10, 10] for [-10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
      × should return [1, 10] for [10, 1] (1ms)
rror

Comment: Una pregunta ¿El algoritmo lo debes escribir a mano o puedes apoyarte en métodos propios de los `Array`, como por ejemplo [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)? Por lo que entiendo necesitas un algoritmo eficiente en cuanto al tiempo. ¿Puedes aclarar ese y otros aspectos para poder ayudarte?

Comment: puedo apoyarme en metodos del array, es unafuncion, que tiene una clase y un constructor function crearClasePersona() {
  class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {

Comment: Por favor añade todos esos detalles a tu pregunta, para que los comentarios no se hagan tan extensos. Agrega los errores, los mensajes del test, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Utilizo el operador spread (...) para expandir el arreglo, y utilizo `Math.min` para el minimo y `Math.max` para el máximo.

```js
let numeros = [-3,45,23,7,31,90,1];

function menorMayor(arreglo){
 return [Math.min(...arreglo),Math.max(...arreglo)]
}

console.log(menorMayor(numeros))
```

Si lo del operador spread te parece demasiado complicado lo puedes hacer de manera verbosa algo así:

```js
let numeros = [-3,45,23,7,31,90,1];

function menorMayor(arreglo){
let menor = Infinity;//un número muy grande
let mayor = -Infinity;//un número muy pequeño
let resultado = [0,0];// el arreglo a devolver

for (let i = 0; i< numeros.length; i++){ 
 if (numeros[i] < menor){
 menor = numeros[i];// el nuevo valor de menor
 resultado[0] = menor;  
 }

 if (numeros[i] > mayor){
 mayor = numeros[i]; //el nuevo valor de mayor
 resultado[1] = mayor;
 }
}
return resultado;
}

console.log(menorMayor(numeros))
```

Comment: Habría que esperar a que nos compartan el mensaje de error

Comment: Creo que la idea del ejercicio es hacerlo a mano, sin la ayuda de métodos como el que propones, pero igual hay que esperar lo que dice el OP.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function menormayor(numeros) {
  var array=[numeros[0], numeros[0]]
  for (var i = 1; i< numeros.length; i++){ 
    if (numeros[i] > array[1]){
      array[1] = numeros[i]; 
    }
    if (numeros[i] < array[0]){
      array[0] = numeros[i]; 
    }
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(menormayor([-12,8,50,23,-22,5,47,32]))
```

Comment: gracias! ahora si me dio bien

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a leer [answer] y a [edit] tu respuesta para que agregues comentarios útiles, indicando el porqué tu respuesta es válida y cómo funciona el código que colocas en la misma. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Bro no se complique la vida para eso existe este tipo de funciones.}

```
  var max =  Math.max(...numeros)
  var min =  Math.min(...numeros)
  var array = [min,max]
  return array
```